# 'The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully' when upgrading Anaconda

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, zsh, apple-m1

I tried to update my Anaconda environment (in root) from python version 3.9.16 to 3.11.4 on my Mac M1, but this message keeps appearing, and it seems that the terminal (-zsh) is stuck in a loop trying to resolve the environment.

Even if I try to remove or update the packages, or uninstall anaconda with anaconda-clean, this message keeps popping and not letting me continue.

At the end I just interrupted the terminal.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/osx-64::boto3==1.24.28=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::mkl_random==1.2.2=py39hb2f4e1b_0
  - defaults/osx-64::scikit-learn-intelex==2021.6.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::mkl_fft==1.3.1=py39h4ab4a9b_0
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/osx-64::boto3==1.24.28=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::mkl_random==1.2.2=py39hb2f4e1b_0
  - defaults/osx-64::scikit-learn-intelex==2021.6.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::mkl_fft==1.3.1=py39h4ab4a9b_0
- ^Zzsh: suspended
```